# Flex gotcha: Something to do w/assigning ArrayCollection elements with ObjectProxy using [] operator

Tags: apache-flex, arraycollection

I have some ActionScript code that assigns an ArrayCollection using:
    `var oProxy:ObjectProxy = new ObjectProxy(myobject);

    arr[i] = oProxy;`

Stepping through this code, I find that `arr[i]` is not what `oProxy` is. I want to know why this failed and what I'm supposed to know about ArrayCollection that would have caused this problem.

Someone told me that using the [] operator to dereference elements in an ArrayCollection is a bad idea. Thus I tried,
`arr.setItemAt(new ObjectProxy(myobject), i);`
and it doesn't seem to make any difference. The assigned element isn't what I expected.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do.  You mention "unpredictable" but don't explain how.  You mention "here is the big problem but don't explain what the problem is or why it is a problem.

Comment: The problem is I try to assign an object to an element in an array, and then that object does not appear in that element. Sometimes no change is made to the element, and sometimes the element is something from another part of the array.

Comment: Though I still don't understand what is causing the problem, it is generally a good idea to avoid the `[]` notation when accessing/setting elements in an `ArrayCollection`. You should use the `getItem()`, `getItemAt()`, `addItem()`, and `addItemAt()`, `setItemAt()`, `addAll()`, or `addAllAt()` methods.

Comment: In fact, if you look at the code in `ArrayList::setItemAt()` or `ArrayList::addItemAt()` (these are the underlying method that `ArrayCollection` uses) you'll see these methods add/remove event listeners that detect changes in the properties of the objects in the collection. This is how data binding works, these events notify components that the array element has changed. So by using the `[]` notation to set the value of an `ArrayCollection` element, you are essentially breaking the binding mechanism.

Comment: I don't understand where the confusion is. I'm trying to assign an element in an ArrayCollection. When I step through the code, I find that what's on the left side of the assignment isn't what was on the right side.
@Sunil I tried changing to setItemAt(), as you recommended, but it didn't seem to change anything. See my edits.

Comment: I think the real problem is not the `setItemAt` (which, by the way, you're not using every time you try to set an index in `arroOutput`), but your loop. I don't think it's doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: Ok, I see people are confused by the entire function, which, I suppose, is extraneous. So I've removed everything except what fails when I step through using debug. Hopefully, it'll be more clear w/out the distraction.

Comment: By *"isn't what I expected"* ..can you describe what fell short of your expectations? Are you getting a totally different object? An object with half of its attributes, or half the attribute depth (i.e. a multi-dimensional object truncated to only the top-level attributes)? I agree with everyone else, though; you're implementing an ArrayCollection, so you should mutate it using the framework methods.

Comment: I would say it's the totally different object. In `myobject` there's a member called `user_id`. The ArrayCollection is 4 long. One member has the `user_id` as 'fred', another 'barney', and the others are 'betty' and 'wilma'. Sometimes an element that starts out as 'fred'  will be assigned by a 'wilma' object but it still stays 'fred'. Then I try to set the 'wilma' element to 'betty', but after I step over, I find that element has 'barney'--crazy stuff like that.

By "framework" do you mean `setItemAt()`? Because I tried that also, at the end of the question.